# Using Virtualenv with Web.py on Dreamhost

Tags: python, virtualenv, web.py, dreamhost

I have set up a web.py app on dreamhost with CGI using these instructions: http://wiki.dreamhost.com/index.php/Web.py. Now, I would like to have the app use a virtualenv and I have created the environment, installed the python modules, and activated the env, but I am not sure what else to do to make the app work with the env and the python modules. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Any link to a good documentation/tutorial would be nice!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to activate the env.
where you would normally:

```
python myapp.py
```

you can run it from the env with

```
/env/bin/python myapp.py
```

However (assuming Linux) It would be advisable to use a Makefile to handle this, something like:

```
env:
    virtualenv --no-site-packages -p python env
    env/bin/pip install web.py

run: env
    /env/bin/python app.py
```

The command "make run" (when entered into the terminal) will then build the env and install web.py (if not already done) then run your code from the virtual env you have made